# Stream list, mapping and setting as a new list

Tags: java, mapping, java-stream

I have a list with entity objects. I want to use a stream based on this list, map all entities on the DTO and assign this new mapped list to the new list. I want to do everything in stream, but I have a problem.

```
movieEntity.getCountries().stream().map(ServiceUtils::toCountryDto).findAny().ifPresent(builder::withCountries);
```

This code does not work because `findAny ()` returns only one object from the list, and I want to set the entire list with the help of withCountries method. How to do it? Using the `Builder` pattern and the `withCountries` method, I want to set the mapped list from the entity.

Comment: This isn't clear - why are you using `findAny()` at all?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `findAny`. You should use another `map()` to convert the instances produced by `ServiceUtils::toCountryDto` to the instances produced by `builder::withCountries` and then collect to a `List` (or some other collection):

```
List<OutputClass> output = 
    movieEntity.getCountries()
               .stream()
               .map(ServiceUtils::toCountryDto)
               .map(builder::withCountries)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I misunderstood your goal, and `builder::withCountries` should just apply an action on each of the instances produced by `ServiceUtils::toCountryDto` (without returning an output), use `forEach`:

```
movieEntity.getCountries()
           .stream()
           .map(ServiceUtils::toCountryDto)
           .forEach(builder::withCountries);
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, you wish to pass the `List` of all the elements of the `Stream` to the `withCountries` method. This can be done by collecting the `Stream` into a `List` and passing that `List` to that method:

```
builder.withCountries(movieEntity.getCountries().stream().map(ServiceUtils::toCountryDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `builder::withCountries` seems to be a `Consumer<CountryDto>`, you can't `map` with that...

Comment: @daniu I may have misunderstood. Made an edit just in case.

Comment: 1 way: I do not want to return the list.

2 way: The method accepts only the list

This is the method from the pattern https://pastebin.com/AwdA60R1

For one object, I would do it like that
```movieEntity.getRating().ifPresent(builder::withRating);``` but I do not know how to send the whole list to stream.

Comment: get countries . map to DTO . set as list wthCountries(list countries)